# How to plot osm-polygons using osmdata and leaflet (in R)?

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I am trying to plot buildings from osm using the leaflet-package in R. Unfortunately with little success and I couldn't find a reproducible example.

In a first step, I define the bounding box and add the 'feature' building:

```
library(dplyr)
library(osmdata)

q1 <- getbb("steckborn, switzerland") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature("building")
```

In a next step, I pass the query to overpass and extract the polygons:

```
out <- osmdata_sf(q1)
poly <- out$osm_polygons
```

Now comes the tricky part. How can I plot them using leaflet? I tried the following:

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addPolygons(lines, col = "blue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work-around on github. Someone noticed the exact same thing and it seems to be in work. I thought I post the link here and hopefully it might help someone in the future.

```
https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/100
```